# Click is not going through on website selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a script that will automatically open to a specific bible verse with it's commentaries open, however, click does not activate the commentary window to open. What is wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://catenabible.com/mt/1")
assert "Catena" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, "mt001001")
elem.click()
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No, no error shows. The code executes normally, however, the click function does not activate the commentary window to open when clicking on the verse.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a wait.
You should wait for the page to complete loading before clicking that element.
The best way to do that is to use the Expected Conditions explicit waits.
The following code should work better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://catenabible.com/mt/1")
assert "Catena" in driver.title
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mt001001 .bibleVerseText"))).click()
```

Comment: Sadly, I am still getting the same result with this code.

Comment: Possibly it is because you tried to click a wrong element. Try the edited answer

Comment: Still no luck. Is there a way to send multiple click commands? Maybe that could fix it?

Comment: Does this throw any kind of exception?

Comment: No, no exceptions are thrown out. Just for some reason, the webpage is not registering the click to activate the commentary panel.

Comment: Instead of the locator I used in the answer try this css_selector `#mt001001 a` and let me know if it worked now

Comment: now it gave an error:

`webdriverClickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.js:166:11
interaction.clickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.js:125:11
clickElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.jsm:204:29
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.jsm:92:31`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I got it to work by using an explicit wait of 2 seconds to allow for the element to be clickable:

```
import time

driver.get("https://catenabible.com/mt/1")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mt001001"]/span').click()
```

It is not ideal to use this wait because it will slow the script down, and you never really know how long will be enough time to wait. But at least it works.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to trigger said javascript if one finds it?

Answer (score 0):

Others answers have stated that you have to click the A tag or the SPAN is not clickable but that isn't true. You just need to wait for the element to be clickable. This opens the right-side Commentaries panel for me.

```
import time

driver.get("https://catenabible.com/mt/1")
assert "Catena" in driver.title
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mt001001"))).click()
count = 0
while len(driver.find_elements((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.commentaryPanel.expanded"))) == 0 and count < 5:
    driver.find_element((By.ID, "mt001001")).click()
    count += 1
    time.sleep(0.25) # brief pause between loops
assert count == 5, "Commentary was not visible after 5 tries"
...
```

Comment: Sadly, this still does not open the commentaries panel for me. It only highlights the specified verse: https://imgur.com/a/VAmh0Er

Comment: I'm using Chrome... maybe that's the difference? I dunno.

Comment: I'll try using Chrome

Comment: I just tried running the same code with chrome to no avail...

Comment: I wonder if it's a weird timing issue for you. Try removing the WebDriverWait and put in a 10 second sleep before the click and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I actually just added more click() functions and it is working now. I don't know why, but it works lol.

`from selenium import webdriver`
`from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`
`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

`driver = webdriver.Firefox()`
`driver.get("https://catenabible.com/mt/1")`
`assert "Catena" in driver.title`
`elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, "mt001001")`
`elem.click()`
`elem.click()`
`elem.click()`
`elem.click()`

Comment: Weird. You could add a loop where you detect if the side panel is out. If it's not, click again. That way you only click as many times as you need to.

Comment: @Rexheters I've added some more sample code to implement the loop I was talking about. Basically check to see if the commentary panel is visible. If not, click again and wait. I added an escape after 5 loops just in case something goes horribly wrong your script doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop.